# How can I convert BASIC into C? Is there an equivalent website where I can compare BASIC and C?

Tags: c, pic, basic, converters

I have some code that I am trying to convert from BASIC to C language.

How would I convert the following in C?

If anyone could help me start I would very much appreciate it. This is for a small project that I am currently doing for myself. I am trying to include SPI and CRC and a few other things.

```
Symbol USB_CHOOSE = PORTD.1

Declare RsOut_Pin PORTD.2
Declare Serial_Baud 38400 
Declare RsOut_Mode True

Dim I As Word
Dim J As Word
Dim IND As Byte
Dim btemp As Byte
Dim SPI_BYTE_OUT As Byte
Dim SPI_BYTE_IN As Byte

 For I = 0 To 99
            CURKEY[I] = 0
            OLDKEY[I] = 0
            APPUI[I] = 0
       Next

        init:       'initialisation first_scan et eco_tap
        FIRST_SCAN_QTA = 0
        FIRST_SCAN_QTB = 0
        COMPTEUR_TAP = 0
        MEM_TAP = 0

        'test init
        'init QTA
        RsOut "*** RESET QTA",13
        Low QTA_RST
        DelayMS 100
        High QTA_RST
        For I = 1 To 25             'attente après reset
            GoSub watch
            DelayMS 100
        Next
        GoSub comm_QTA
        GoSub read_crc_eeprom_QTA
        If INIT_ERROR_COUNTER > 0 Then
            '***
            'DelayMS 200
            GoSub write_setup_QTA     
        EndIf
        GoSub read_setup_eeprom_QTA          
        GoSub cal_all_QTA                    
        GoSub chech_cal_QTA                  


         main:          GoSub watch

           High PORTA.3:DelayUS 30:Low PORTA.3

            Case 6 ' t T
                    GoSub gesture_simple
                    If GESTURE = 1 Then
                        BUFFER[1 + NB_TOUCH] = $17
                    EndIf
                    If GESTURE = 5 Then
                        T_REL = $17
                    EndIf
                    GoSub sendcode
```

Comment: The first thing to do is to learn the basics of the C language. Then rewrite the BASIC code in C. For that you must of course understand how the BASIC code works.

Comment: try and convert it , then ask any questions about what you don't know how to convert, most of this looks like a straight forward conversion

Answer (score 2):

1. If conditions and for loops in BASIC have a direct substitute in C.
2. Subroutines can be replaced by functions with no parameters.
3. Case statement is analogous to the `switch case` statement in C.
4. `DelayMS` seems to be a system subroutine. You will need to write a custom function in C or find a library function for a delay.
5. Regarding variables, you can go two ways.

5a. Use `int` for `Bytes` and `Words`. This is sufficient for beginners and for your program.

5b. As you get more knowledge you can look into `uint8_t uint16_t uint32_t` for 8 bit, 16 bit and 32 bit unsigned integers, and `sint8_t sint16_t sint32_t` for signed integers. You need to `#include <inttypes.h>` for the above.

Comment: On the 2nd one. When you are transpiling manually, you should actually think about equivalent being readable or good enough in other language, for example, it would be more beneficial to just rewrite subroutine into proper function which actually does take in parameters. It will still compile and work the same, but at least will be more organized and won't pollute global scope with random variables.

Comment: This is a strange dialect of BASIC.  Looks like the arrays begin at 0 so you shouldn't have a problem there but remember to +1 to the declaration (can't see the declaration in your code)

Comment: Would Dim I As Word  (BASIC)

I = Word ;

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you like to try BaCon. It's a free Basic to C converter. [BaCon](http://www.basic-converter.org/)